# Filter duplicates in MongoDB C++

Tags: c++, mongodb, duplicates

I am looking to find all duplicates in my collection by flagging duplicates based on the date.  The following was my attempt but I am not sure how to use cmdResult within update.  Any clues?

```
//filter duplicates
bson::bo cmdResult;
bool ok = c.runCommand(dbcol, BSON("distinct" << "date"), cmdResult);
c.update(dbcol,Query("date"<<cmdResult<<NOT<<"_id"), BSON("$set"<<BSON("noise"<<"true")), false, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "distinct" command will return you a list of all unique "date" values there are in the collection. But what you need is a list of "date" values that occur more than once.

You can get this list using the aggregate command, by grouping by "date" and counting the entries, then matching for counts > 1:

```
aggregate([
    { $group: { "_id": "$name", count: {$sum:1} } },
    { $match: { $gt: [ count, 1 ] } }
])
```

You would then update your collection (multi:true) by querying for "date" IN that list, setting the "noise" field:

```
update( {"name": {$in: [<list>]} },{$set: {"noise": true} }, true, false )
```

For help on aggregation, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/